# ArrayAdapter is null even after getting a string array as a parameter

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on the Sunshine app in the Developing Android App course by Udacity. Currently stuck in lesson 2. I've listed down the MainActivity.java that contains a listview that is populated by a network call in the AsyncTask as an inner class in the MainActivity.java. But the application crashes, due to a null pointer exception, as the array adapter is null. I've tried debugging, and the weekForecast (i.e., the ArrayList that stores the parsed data, and is a parameter to the creation of the ArrayAdapter) does have valid parsed data. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    GettingWeatherFromNetwork gettingWeatherFromNetwork = new GettingWeatherFromNetwork();
    gettingWeatherFromNetwork.execute("94043");
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.action_settings : return true;
        case R.id.action_refresh : GettingWeatherFromNetwork gettingWeatherFromNetwork = new GettingWeatherFromNetwork();
            gettingWeatherFromNetwork.execute("94043");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class GettingWeatherFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = GettingWeatherFromNetwork.class.getSimpleName();
    //Removed API KEY. But it is a part of the main code I'm running.
    private final String API_KEY = "  ";

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String forecastJsonStr = null;
        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int noOfDays = 7;

        try {

            final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String MODE_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String COUNT_PARAM = "cnt";
            final String KEY_PARAM = "appid";

            Uri builtURI = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(MODE_PARAM,format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(COUNT_PARAM, String.valueOf(noOfDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(KEY_PARAM,API_KEY)
                    .build();

            String Url = builtURI.toString();
            URL url = new URL(Url);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(e));
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(e));
                }
            }
        }

        String [] weatherForecast = new String[0];
        WeatherParser weatherParser = new WeatherParser();
        try {
            weatherForecast = weatherParser.getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,7);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weatherForecast;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] s) {
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to call this listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); in your onPostExecute

Comment: Please set listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); inside onPostExecute();

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. It works. Why does it not update if i globally update the arrayadapter and set the adapter to the listview through the onCreate?

Comment: You haven't initialised your adapter therefore you are getting null pointer exception

Comment: Because when `listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` line executing `arrayAdapter` object is `null`

Comment: But why is it null, when ArrayAdapter is a global variable, then ideally it should update it when onPost executes?

Comment: Its null because you are initializing arrayAdapter from background thread, but you set adapter on your list before background task result.This is the reason when you set it from onPostExecute () it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

from onCreate method and add it in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask, after initialising the arrayAdapter.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] s) {
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);

    //set adapter set to listview after initialzing it.

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```